# "Edit with IDLE" not in context menu

Tags: python-2.7, contextmenu, python-idle

Recently I have installed Python 2.7.13 in my Windows 10.
When I try to open my python program by right clicking on it, but I can not find option `Edit with IDLE`.
I have tried solutions that are given in other stack overflow questions but still not working.

Answers that I have found on other Stack Overflow questions are....

**Answer 1**

`Right Click on file and select default program for .py file **python.exe**`

**Answe 2**

`Change in Registry key`

But they didn't worked for me.

Comment: You should expand on _other solutions_ so we _may_ offer different approaches if there is any.

Comment: For me, there are only entries for recent 3.x versions.  I cannot remember if it ever worked for 2.x.

Comment: How did you install Python?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid...Download Python 2.7.13 from Python.org and installed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution...

At time of saving python code, there will be two extensions displayed `.py` and `.pyw`.I saved my file using `.pyw` extension i.e. instead of saving as `my.py` saved as `my.pyw`. After that again right click on file and there is an option for `Edit with IDLE`.

Answer (score 0):

**BOYS. I DID IT.** I really don't know anything about coding or whatnot, but I had the same problem. In my case, I had idle 3.10 downloaded, but "edit with idle" only appeared with Idle 2.7. I also had "edit with Idle - 3.5 (32-bit)" but this didn't open.

Anyways, so I went to the registry
Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.File\Shell\

...and I saw the 2 folders. So, I made a new folder, or "key" I guess, and titled it "Edit with IDLE 3.10". I'm pretty much following the keys and codes in the first "Edit with Idle" (2.7) key box. So, in this folder, I made the key "command", and located where "pythonw.exe" for 3.10 was. I found it in my appdata folder, for some reason; it wasn't where 2.7 was, as 2.7 was just in my C:drive. Anyways, I copied this entire path and pasted the value for Idle 2.7 into the newly made command folder for 3.10 in my case.
I replaced the location paths of 2.7 where I found the specific file the value put for python with my 3.10 version.
Thus; I changed two parts in the code, separated by its spaces.
"C:\Users...\Python310\pythonw.exe" "C:\Users...\Python310\Lib\idlelib\idle.pyw" -e "%1"

Then, the context menu I created in registry showed up in my folder, and it opened the 3.10 version of IDLE! I hope this helps anyone else who didn't figure it out yet. I'm surprised it worked for me, man.